# How to link hundreds of domains without listing them in linker property in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website running on many many different domains and the data from all of them I want to gather in one Google Analytics property combined. According to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en I need to set up the same code on each domain and list all of domains inside the linker property. But is there a way to NOT list all of the domains and/or to replace them with some sort of identifiers or individual properties?

I expect instead of

```
ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-1.com', 'example-3.com'] );
```

to be able to set up something like this

```
ga('linker:autoLink', [xxxxx-1, xxxxx-2, ..., xxxxxx-1000] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sessions/traffic from each of the domains never cross as in people visiting your site using mydomain1.com won't be going to mydomain2.com in the same session or coming back to mydomain2.com then you can ignore the cross-domain tracking.

The linker will append ga parameters to the end of links that link out to your other domains. If you want to be a little more discreet about it, you can use GTM: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164469?hl=en, though people can still find them, it is just slightly less obvious.

Comment: The sessions/traffic from each of the domains will never cross. Did I get it right that in this case I can just add the same standard GA tracking code without linker and all sessions and data will appear in GA panel under one first domain I created property for?

Comment: Yes, you can just add in the standard code for the same property on all those domains. If you want to look at the domains separately, you can just use the "hostname" dimension.